# Typescript groupBy "Cannot be used to index type '{}'" when trying to add key to reduce object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to get the following function to compile without TS erros:

```
function groupBy<Item>(items: Item[], key: keyof Item) {
  return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    (acc[item[key]] = acc[item[key]] || []).push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

But assigning to `acc` results in `Type 'Item[keyof Item]' cannot be used to index type '{}'.`

I've tried a lot of other things like playing with `Extract` and `Record` but just results in more errors e.g.

```
export function groupBy<Item extends Record<string, object>, K extends Extract<keyof Item, string>>(
  items: Item[],
  key: K
) {
  return items.reduce((acc: Record<K, Item[]>, item: Item) => {
    (acc[item[key]] = acc[item[key]] || []).push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

P.S the functionality is like lodash [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) e.g.

```
groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length');
// Result: { '3': ['one', 'two'], '5': ['three'] }
```

How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Of what type do you expect the return value to be?

Comment: It should be an object like this: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

Comment: Right now, TypeScript is inferring the output type to be `{ [el: Item]: Item[] }`, which is not valid. I think you want `acc[key]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd type it like this:

```
function groupBy<T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T>(
  items: readonly T[],
  key: K
) {
  return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    (acc[item[key]] = acc[item[key]] || []).push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<T[K], T[]>);
}
```

The important bits are: mutually constraining `K` and `T` so that `K` is a key of `T` where the property `T[K]` is itself suitable to be a key of an object; and asserting that the accumulator will eventually be of type `Record<T[K], T[]>`, an object whose keys are the same as `T[K]` and whose values are an array of `T`.

Then you can test that it works:

```
const g = groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length');
// const g: Record<number, string[]>

console.log(
  Object.keys(g).map(k => k + ": " + g[+k].join(", ")).join("; ")
); // 3: one, two; 5: three
```

The type of `g` is inferred as `{[k: number]: string[]}`, an object with a numeric index signature whose properties are string arrays.  As another example, to make sure it works:

```
interface Shirt {
  size: "S" | "M" | "L"
  color: string;
}
const shirts: Shirt[] = [
  { size: "S", color: "red" },
  { size: "M", color: "blue" },
  { size: "L", color: "green" },
  { size: "S", color: "orange" }];

const h = groupBy(shirts, "size");
// const h: Record<"S" | "M" | "L", Shirt[]>

console.log(JSON.stringify(h));
//{"S":[{"size":"S","color":"red"},{"size":"S","color":"orange"}],"M":[{"size":"M","color":"blue"}],"L":[{"size":"L","color":"green"}]}
```

Here we see that a `Shirt` has a `size` property from a limited selection of string literals, and `groupBy(shirts, "size")` returns a value inferred to be of type `{S: Shirt[], M: Shirt[], L: Shirt[]}.`

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE5xABwEIE8A8AKogKYAeUJYAJgM6IBKJEcq1+A0gDSIAK6mEqii4OJXAD4eHUhSp1EAa3FxgiQhIAUAKESIYlALa0AXIlQkAhtQQAbXOoDaAXS66l4sx20BKRAG93CygQVCQDEmMAOgtqEAgSTU1LCAgeCMM-AF4JAPc9ZNTHDMdlXGdnRCzEFIhio1LxCsQAHxbEFx8ozBBaAAtNDJ8AbnzzEhCwmtTRvQBfHn85mvomFjYiRw5XJ2cJEe057W0WMFooFCqUdCw8TUcAcgQSB54HqAB3OFfEd76LF47B62KjIKB9B4HAD0UMQp3OKDMa1Y7DAIEMACMhDxzqgYGBkC4JMd4XAQVFbHBkDo9AB5DEAK2YUCiZVommQXUMlkwmkUVVy-IA1IgAERmUWIEWEoWKZxRBlwfGaUU8UU+LqK5Wi4Ziny+XUwxAAZjMzx4nzguoArGZwQDjvjKKhgCkSIgAMp9GDCPJ6WgwABeJAlHsl7VFAFlw2KADKi9wsSmoMy4-HIUZHeEXfo+qCmT3e4QuK6Odz+RAB4Oh1VwsmsCWxSULcuVoMhsXRnhJhtijG2EAkZs8VtVjui+Pd+spsVoEhUYej9s1qfJiWsSwEoeIObOUYnBAIvpXNAYHC4TS54S0NVj9WjI3ZxB9JHMFH4UVh1qdmMT2tevMiRJQ8yRICkqU0AApD1aQAOSiNMCRgYALz6DUHyhfxP3FRwsLvExsK4UUe1QcVRSbBY8PbMiwyIkiyI3LdRV3IjoxMXDRXwqNVWI6cyP7QdmNcP92Ko4MyMnXjkzIucF13I5tCAA)

Comment: Unfortunately it has an error with TS > 2.9 at T[K] due to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#keyof-now-includes-string-number-and-symbol-keys Tried `K extends Extract<keyof T, string>` but to no avail :/. Guessing that playground has `keyofStringsOnly: true` but don't want to assume that for consumers of my lib

Comment: What particular error are you talking about and where does it occur?  Playground is using TS3.9 and not constraining `keyof` to strings, as evidenced [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgNYBcieApgJ5zCIYCUiA3gFAQIDOUirR7ATjGAHNEAXmIBuRAHpJiEjx5wejAL5A).

Comment: Edit: The original code worked fine when I changed compileOptions.module from "ESNext" to "UMD" or "ES6" huh (tbh I don't understand the difference between ESNext/ES6/ES2019 I thought they used the same import/export module syntax) :/